# Fortify "sourceanalyzer -show-build-ids" does now display any build id after successful build for .NET Core 3.1 x64

Tags: .net-core, fortify, static-code-analysis

I have a solution contained 4 projects:
Console netcoreapp3.1,Standard Class Library 2.1,Worker Service netcoreapp3.1,xunit test project under netcoreapp3.1

I did:

1. sourceanalyzer -b * -clean
2. sourceanalyzer -b X.sln msbuild "C:\x\X.sln" /nologo /v:n /t:Rebuild
3. sourceanalyzer -show-build-ids
   No results
4. sourceanalyzer.exe -scan -b x.sln -f "C:\x\Security\x.fpr"

Output:
[error]: Unable to load build session with ID "x.sln". See log file for more details.

I am using VS 2019 latest update Version 16.7.6,
Fortify Static Code Analyzer 20.1.0.0158 (using JRE 1.8.0_181)

Comment: https://community.microfocus.com/t5/Fortify-User-Discussions/sourceanalyzer-show-build-ids-does-now-display-any-build-id/td-p/2834682

Answer (score 2):

`Unable to load build session with ID` error message has been thrown for many versions now if Fortify does not support the project's version of .NET Framework. Download and install the latest version of Fortify Source Code Analyzer and scan again. Be sure to close Visual Studio first.

Happened to me after upgrading a Visual Studio solution from .NET Core 2.2 (aka `netcoreapp2.2` in csproj) to .NET Core 3.1 `netcoreapp3.1`. Removing Fortify 19.2 and installing 20.1 did the trick. In your case however it seems you have the latest Fortify version 20.1.

To confirm this is the problem:

1. Verify Fortify [Supported Languages](https://www.microfocus.com/documentation/fortify-static-code-analyzer-and-tools/2010/Fortify_Sys_Reqs_20.1.0/index.htm#SCA/SCA_SupportedLangs.htm) for your version, v20.1 in this example
2. Manually delete project "bin" and "obj" folders -- even after a Clean Solution some can remain
3. Look for "netcoreapp" in log file (replace "20.1" here with your fortify version) *C:\Users\MYUSER\AppData\Local\Fortify\sca20.1\log* -- for me it showed .NET Core v2.2 references instead of my project's v3.1 tipping me off to the need for a Fortify upgrade